# Is there a way to suppress "procedure too large" error in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am debugging an old application writeen in VB6. I am getting this compile error after doing a lot of debugging. Is there a way to stop these type of errors or should I do the manual process of dividing the big procedure into smaller ones.

Comment: How *big* does it need to be to trigger that? Hopefully there aren't that many to deal with .. and what made them [suddenly] "too large"?

Comment: Well you could have chopped it up into smaller ones by now. And the code would be 'better'.

Comment: Looks like there isn't: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vb6+%22procedure+too+large%22  Are you expecting a different answer here than on all those other forums?

Comment: It has around 2600 lines and it is a existing one which runs without any error. It gives error while debugging only by adding it into a .vbg group.

Comment: "It has around 2600 lines " - what could possibly go wrong.....

Comment: looks like it is not possible to suppress this error..I have removed that project from the vbg group as I didn't need to debug that but I needed to stop running for removing the project, which I didn't want as it has already done a lot of processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to suppress this error.

Answer (score 4):

Your **compiled** procedure cannot exceed 64kb. You should break it up into different sub routines as [advised in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa264541).

Or for VBA macros (which your code isn't) You might get this error message if the macro has been created using the 64-bit version of Office. [Workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983044)

Comment: It should be 32 bit only as I don't think any 64-bit of vb6 enterprise edition is available and another point is that I am working on Windows server 2003 which is itself 32 bit.

Comment: Agreed with the splitting of the operations. If you have that much going on inside of one event or routine, then you should be recycling code better or have a better design for you code. What are you trying to achieve with such a long piece of code?